# How do I re-connect a google adwords property with my analytics account?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I've deleted my adwords property at my analytics account because it didn't connect properly. Now it's not possible to re-connect them. The usual way to do this, is:

Analytics->Admin->Adwords Linking-> Select AdWords-accounts

But my adwords account isn't vissible anymore because I removed it. How do I get it back?

Answer (score 0):

There's an API for that. [AdWords linking API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAdWordsLinksGuide)

```
// Construct a list of AdWordsAccounts.
AdWordsAccount adWordsAccount = new AdWordsAccount();
adWordsAccount.setCustomerId("123-456-7890");
List<AdWordsAccount> adWordsAccounts = Arrays.asList(adWordsAccount);

// Construct the body of the request.
EntityAdWordsLink adWordsLink = new EntityAdWordsLink();
adWordsLink.setAdWordsAccounts(adWordsAccounts);
adWordsLink.setName("AdWords Link");

try{
  analytics.management().webPropertyAdWordsLinks().insert("123456",
      "UA-123456-1", adWordsLink).execute();
} catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
  System.err.println("There was a service error: "
      + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
      + e.getDetails().getMessage());
}
```

Or simply do as you stated in the web interface:
Analytics->Admin->adwords Linking->New Link Group